# Swift: Estimated Height Not Working for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, autolayout, snapkit

My problem is that setting the estimated height for my collection view layout does not work. Specifically, the cell does not resize dynamically.

My hypothesis is my AutoLayout constraints are not set properly on my cell / `UILabel`

---

First, I created a custom `UICollectionViewCell`

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit


class BubbleCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var label:UILabel!
    var spacer:UIView!
    
    var text:String = "" {
        didSet {
            guard label != nil else {return}
            label.text = text
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        spacer = UIView()
        contentView.addSubview(spacer)
        
        label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7)
            make.top.right.equalTo(self.safeAreaLayoutGuide).inset(10)
        }
        
        spacer.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.label.snp.bottom)
            make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Next, I created a custom `UICollectionView`. Below is the function I use to generate my "layout"

```swift
func getLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize.init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(200))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem.init(layoutSize: size)
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitems: [item])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection.init(group: group)
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.init(section: section)
}
```

---

Now, when I run my app, you can see the cell (with the red background) has not resized its height to fit my `UILabel`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved via implementing my class like so.

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit


class BubbleCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var label:UILabel!
    var background:UIView!
    
    var text:String = "" {
        didSet {
            guard label != nil else {return}
            label.text = text
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupUI(spacing:CGFloat=2) {
                    
        label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        background = UIView()
        background.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        background.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        background.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(background)
        contentView.sendSubviewToBack(background)
                
        label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10 + spacing)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.7)
        }
        
        background.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.label).inset(-10)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.label).offset(10)
            make.left.equalTo(self.label).inset(-15)
            make.right.equalTo(self.label).offset(15)
        }
    }
}
```